# Load tinymce after html changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I am trying to write a drag and drop html editor using tinymce and initialize it as inline, it is work correctly.
But in a part I have a duplicator of an element that do this:

```
$(obj).parent()[0].outerHTML += "\n\n"+$(obj).parent()[0].outerHTML;
```

After execute this part, tinymce do not work for this element and new element that created.

In another part I have a html code editor, if user change html codes tinymce do not work at all!!

why??

I change duplicator to:

```
$(obj).parent()[0].outerHTML += "\n\n"+$(obj).parent()[0].outerHTML;
initTinymce();    //this is my initilizer function
```

But...

Comment: Try something like this:

    `$(obj).parent().html("\n\n" +$(obj).parent().html());`

Comment: Have you tried using [the HTML characters](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html) rather than a backslash-escaped newline? `&#10;&#13;`

Comment: I try both of your suggests but...